# Error in executing RaptorXML command through subprocess.call() in python

Tags: python, subprocess, altova, xbrl

I am trying to execute the RaptorXML+XBRL command through `subprocess.call()` from a python script. The syntax is:

```
result = call(["/opt/Altova/RaptorXMLXBRLServer2015/bin/raptorxmlxbrl xbrl","--listfile", joblist],shell=True )
```

Where `joblist = "valSECfilings.jobs"`. But when I execute this python script I get this error:

```
Error: No value for mandatory argument 'FILE' specified.
Usage:
   raptorxmlxbrl valxbrl [options] FILE...

   valxbrl can be abbreviated with: xbrl
```

When I execute this command directly on the terminal I do not get any error:

```
/opt/Altova/RaptorXMLXBRLServer2015/bin/raptorxmlxbrl xbrl --listfile "valSECfilings.jobs"
```

Can anyone help me pointing what might be wrong here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is unfortunately somewhat unclear on this point, but when you pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.call`, the `args` parameter is supposed to be a single string instead of a list.  It should be a list of the command and individual argments if `shell=False` (the default).

So both of these are correct:

```
result = call(["/opt/Altova/RaptorXMLXBRLServer2015/bin/raptorxmlxbrl", "xbrl", "--listfile", joblist])
```

or

```
result = call("/opt/Altova/RaptorXMLXBRLServer2015/bin/raptorxmlxbrl xbrl --listfile " + joblist, shell=True)
```

I'd prefer the first (non-shell) version because the second one means you have to make sure the `joblist` string doesn't contain spaces or improper quote characters.

Comment: True, the space is the problem. When you call "/opt/Altova/RaptorXMLXBRLServer2015/bin/raptorxmlxbrl_SPACE_xbrl" is not interpreted as "raptorxmlxbrl" and the argument "xbrl" but as a command "raptorxmlxbrl xbrl", which obviously does not exists as an executable. Frankly the documentation is pretty clear about that and it also has a very easy to analyze example:  subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])

Comment: Examples do not suffice as proper documentation, IMO.  However, upon re-reading the documentation I'll note that there is a comprehensive explanation of how `args` is interpreted, but it's under the `subprocess.Popen` section, and you have to read 6 paragraphs before you get to the part that explains exactly how a sequence is interpreted on Unix.

Comment: Of course example != documentation. I just mentioned that it is a nice way to illustrate what is already explained there. But I guess it is confusing to have to look at Popen when you just want to use call(). This should be changed by at least adding a link in the call() section to the place where args is explained in a greater detail.